# Threading is not allowing to save file in python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, flask

I have a simple app.py file, I'm sending some file from Postman. I'm trying to receive the file and pass to another thread as argument. I'm unable to save file in threaded method. It throws `ValueError: read of closed file`

But I can save the file before thread method calling.

My app.py file looks like this,

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)

def handle_video_input(data_file, required_args):
    path = os.path.abspath(data_file.filename)
    data_file.save(path)

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process_input():
    data_file = request.files['objectfile']
    required_args = {'type':'something'}
    training_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_video_input, args=[data_file, required_args])
    training_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Why am I getting this error? 
What's wrong in my code?

Any help would be appreciable.

I tried different ways of passing args. None of them worked. I suspect something wrong with threading. 
Please clarify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request` object is only available in the thread serving the request.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context

In order to process the file, you can save the file in the current thread, and then you will be able to pass a reference to the saved file's path to a new thread to process the content.